# Is mysqli_* a better choice than mysql_*?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have used PHP for years, and I always use mysql_* functions.

I don't really mind it a lot, but does mysqli_* function worth me to have a try? If I am gonna make a new project, which one should I choose?

Any advice is welcomed. Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: It is the time of `PDO`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: between mysql and mysqli you should choose mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of mysql_* is [discouraged](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Answer (score 2):

Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).
(canonical answer from [PHP chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), feel free to join)

Comment: Thank you a lot! Special thanks to @Matei Mihai , who really read my question!

Comment: @Leigh every post is a repost repost... are you the original author of the answer? I can name a few.

Comment: @webarto No, why so serious? We both see this copy/paste 3-4x a day, just remarking on how it's left its normal home and made it into an answer.

Comment: @Leigh I'll never wake up at 6AM again, everything looks different, carry on with pasting ol' chap :) I'm proud of us :P